# python - how to iterate through values of dict

Tags: python, dictionary, mapreduce

I have a dict I want to iterate through to find all values that contain the key. My output would be a separate dict that would contain the numbers from each dict value without the key in the value or each specific keys values in the final

```
dict_in =   
   {'6': ['2,9,8,10'], '1': ['3,5,8,9,10,12'], '4': ['2,5,7,8,9'], '2': ['3,4,7,6,13'], '12': ['1,7,5,9'], '3': ['9,11,10,1,2,13'], '10': ['1,3,6,11'], '5': ['4,1,7,11,12'], '13': ['2,3'], '8': ['1,6,4,11'], '7': ['5,2,4,9,12'], '11': ['3,5,10,8'], '9': ['12,1,3,6,4,7']}
```

so the output would be like this:

```
 {'6':['3,4,7,13,1,3,11,1,4,11,12,1,3,4,7'] , '4':['3,4,6,13,1,11,12,1,6,11,12,12,1,3,6'],'13': ['4,7,6,9,11,10,1']}
```

I am a beginner and I do not even know where to start. Would it be easier to convert it to a list of lists?

Comment: I do not understand what condition is used to achieve the expected output.

Comment: He seems to want to switch his key values, with values from any other key that contain the original key as value but not have it included. Complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing about your problem that is an extra challenge. That is for you or some other good samaritan to solve. This is just a nudge in your direction. Your values for the keys is actually a single string. Now if it was actual integers, the problem is not too complicated. Also to note, your expected output that you wrote based on your requirement is actually typed wrong, you missed a few values.

In case of having integers instead of a string, I can show you one approach that as a beginner you can hopefully understand:

```
dict_in = {'6': [2,9,8,10], '1': [3,5,8,9,10,12], '4': [2,5,7,8,9], '2': [3,4,7,6,13], '12':  [1,7,5,9], '3': [9,11,10,1,2,13], '10': [1,3,6,11], '5': [4,1,7,11,12], '13': [2,3], '8' :[1,6,4,11], '7': [5,2,4,9,12], '11': [3,5,10,8], '9': [12,1,3,6,4,7]}

dict_out = {}

for key in dict_in:
    if key == "6" or key == "4" or key == "13":
        for k,v in dict_in.items():
            for y in v:
                if int(key) in v and y != int(key):
                    dict_out.setdefault(key, []).append(y)


Output:
{'6': [3, 4, 7, 13, 1, 3, 11, 1, 4, 11, 12, 1, 3, 4, 7], '4': [3, 7, 6, 13, 1, 7, 11, 12, 1, 6, 11, 5, 2, 9, 12, 12, 1, 3, 6, 7], '13': [3, 4, 7, 6, 9, 11, 10, 1, 2]}
```

Last note, I have no clue whatsoever for why on Earth, you wanted the only keys left to be 6,4 and 13.
In any case, do not consider this as a full answer.

Comment: Those are not the only keys I wanted left. I wanted all left. The numbers are supposed to represent connections and the goal is to find people they might be connected with by finding people who are actual contacts (in the list of a connection - a # in the value) create an intermediate store of potential connections and reducing it down to numbers that 2,3 or 4 connections have.

Comment: I see. Did you type in the dictionary by yourself or did it come from somewhere? If it comes out of some text file it would probably be easier to manipulate the data first, so it is inserted into values as integers instead of a single string. Also, if you want to keep all existing keys (in your description, people) to check all connections, just remove the `if key == "6" or key == "4" or key == "13":` and adjust indentation of the rest.

Comment: yes it came out of a mapper file. I went back and adjusted it so it is integers. I will check to make sure it is integers.

Comment: Then you should be good. Can't estimate speed but for this amount of data it doesn't matter. If we were talking about a much larger sample size, it might be different.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I converted it to int before I loaded in in the first dict.Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Now sure what you mean, so just created something that will cover most part. Change it with what you want.

```
dict_in = {'6': ['2,9,8,10'], '1': ['3,5,8,9,10,12'], '4': ['2,5,7,8,9'], '2': ['3,4,7,6,13'], '12':  ['1,7,5,9'], '3': ['9,11,10,1,2,13'], '10': ['1,3,6,11'], '5': ['4,1,7,11,12'], '13': ['2,3'], '8' :['1,6,4,11'], '7': ['5,2,4,9,12'], '11': ['3,5,10,8'], '9': ['12,1,3,6,4,7']}

dict_out = {}
for key, values in dict_in.items():
    for item in values:
        if True:#your condition
            if key in dict_out.keys():
                dict_out[key].append(item)
            else:
                dict_out[key] = [item]

print(dict_out)
```

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong but I used this and got back the original dict in the dict_out

Comment: Well I wasn't sure what you exactly wanted so it wrote this code. It basically tells you how to use dict.items(), dict.keys(), etc So that you get to know how it works and then make changes according to your problem